# Connecting to AWS RDS DBInstance with MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am trying to evaluate AWS RDS to use as possible DB for our application. I have created a DBInstance(micro) and added IP security group. I am able to connect to the DBInstance from Xampp shell command line and i am able to run queries from that.

But when i try to connect with workbench to the same DBInstance, it gives me error that 'MySQL server has gone away'. 
Following are the steps i followed to connect with workbench:

1. Give the Endpoint address of DBInstance as Hostname.
2. Port : 3306
3. Set the username and password to master user and its password.

My database is completely new, I have just created a plain DB and trying to connect with workbench right away. I am using workbench version 5.2.25.

Any ideas on what am i missing? And yes, I am just a beginner with MySQL and AWS.

**Edit:** As asked by RolandoMySQLDBA, i have run the query `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and in the result i get one row with two columns `USER()=ei@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` and `CURRENT_USER()=ei@%`. `ei` is the master username for my RDS DBInstance. And the column `USER()` has my ip address after `@`.

I tried using both `ei@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` and `ei@%` with workbench, but i get access denied error .

Comment: Please go to the XAMPP Shell Command Line and run this Query : `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and post the results of the query in the question.

Comment: Added result to the question.

Comment: Have you tried using `ei` as the username in the Workbench config of the connection?

Comment: @ypercube Yes I have tried that also.

Comment: Highly recommend to try Sequel Pro. Had tons of connection problems, timeouts, slow query execution etc... with workbench on my rds instance but once moved to Sequel everything just runs perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have instantiated a MySQL RDS Instance, you want to create a DB Security Group

- First Create a DB Security Group
- Under "Security Group Details", set one of the following connection types

  - `CIDR/IP`
  - `EC2 Security Group`
- Assign Address/Mask
- Make sure you do not have a proxy/firewall causing interference

Comment: I have already done that and i am able to connect to RDS instance with my local shell command line. But can't connect with workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is working perfect on MySQL workbench. I remember following these steps mentioned on this link, maybe it helps:

http://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/